# Display Web Control with Ext Window in a normal page ad Content

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I have a web control having a
1

```
ext:window
```

and which can be displayed as a popup window.

Im required to display this web control as a popup in some scenarios and as a content of a page in other scenarios

my issue is how to display this web control content within a page without popup approach. (as just a page with ext controls) ?

What is the best approach for this using ext if ext:window is not stable ?

Comment: You have some ASP.NET page without Ext.NET controls and on some user action you want to show ext:Window with some Ext.NET controls?

Comment: yes that what i required

Comment: How have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes i was able to create a window in a client page and put the webcontrol inside that window (Web control has no window contains items in a pannel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iframe which created by some jQuery plugin or you can use clear ExtJS and import minimum package for ExtJS Window class using scripts Dynamic Load. Some start information you can read [here.](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system)